# Can I control the DIOs of SX1276 using another Microcotroller?

Tags: arduino, embedded, sx1276

I want to know if I can use the 6 DIO pins on the SX1276 LoRa module as regular GPIO pins.

Here is the context. I have an Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect Board.
https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/nano-rp2040-connect

7 GPIO pins of the uBlox Nina in that board can be controlled by the Arduino Program using regular Arduino functions like digitalWrite() etc.
Is this common?

If at all this is possible with the SX1276 as well, how do I go about it?

Comment: You'd start by reading the datasheet of the module... have you done this, what did it say, was something unclear...

Comment: I should have gone through the datasheet before posting the question. Looks like those DIOs can be only mapped to some interrupts like TX Done, RX Done, FIFO Empty etc.